# Find the value of $k$ in the exponent

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I am trying to calculate the $k$ value in this equation:

$\dfrac1{n^c} \le \left(1 - \dfrac2{n(n-1)} \right)^k$

by using the logarithm,  I am getting for $k$:

$\log_{1- 2/n(n-1)} n^{-c} \le k$

is that correct? And ist there any way to simplify the result of $k$?

Answer (score 0):

If you take logs,
$\dfrac1{n^c} \le \left(1 - \dfrac2{n(n-1)} \right)^k
$
becomes
$-c\log(n)
\le k \log\left(1 - \dfrac2{n(n-1)} \right)
$.

Since
$\log\left(1 - \dfrac2{n(n-1)} \right)
< 0$,
dividing by it
reverses the sign
of the inequality,
so we get
$\frac{-c\log(n)}{\log\left(1 - \dfrac2{n(n-1)} \right)}
\ge k 
$.

If $n$ is large compared with $k$,
the right side is about
$1 - \dfrac{2k}{n(n-1)} 
$,
so we get,
as an approximation,
$\dfrac1{n^c} \le 1 - \dfrac{2k}{n(n-1)} 
$
or
$k
\le \frac12 n(n-1)(1-n^{-c})
$.